# Regarding aggregating messages

Tags: java, jms, spring-integration, spring-jms

I am asking a simple question with regard to JMS that I am implementing through spring integration and spring also, But I am stuck up at one situation please advise me, let say I am getting 5000 messages in a queue and I want to aggregate in a group of 20 messages then forward it , means I want some sort of aggregation which will take a 20 messages from 5000 messages and will forward that 20 messages ,Please advise how to achieve this.

I was also going through this pattern also..http://www.eaipatterns.com/Aggregator.html

Comment: Forget "patterns".  Please define the *problem*!  Q: What exactly do you mean by "aggregate"?  What criterion determines which message to forward, and which messages to drop?  Why exactly do you need to drop anything at all?  What are the consequences of dropping a "wrong" message? *What are the actual "requirements"*???

Comment: please advise can I achieve this in core java also ..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had that similar problem, and i solved it creating a counter in each message with an atomicLong.

Then , the releast strategy will release the messages every after X messages, based on that counter ( stored as a message_id header )

```
    <int:aggregator ...
    release-strategy-expression="size() == ${max.size}"
     correlation-strategy-expression="new java.lang.Double(new java.lang.Double(headers.message_id) / ${max.size}).longValue()"
     />
```

And hey, it works.

Comment: could you please post the complete code that will be a great help,Thanks inadvance

Comment: That's the magic .. there's no code at all. As user mfisher states, all you need is the xml definition for the release strategy and the correlation strategy. When to release messages and how to group messages

Answer (score 1):

This section of the Spring Integration reference manual should provide all the information you need:
http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/docs/2.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#aggregator

Basically you want a release-strategy that returns true when the message group size reaches 20, and you want a correlation-strategy that simply considers all messages to be in the same group (unless you do have some other indicator of group membership).

Hope that helps.
-Mark